# Suddenly, Windows 10 won't boot up with USB device attached

Tags: windows-10

I have a USB dongle with ethernet and extra USB ports, and an external hard drive attached to one of those ports. None of this has ever been a problem - I've always been able to reboot, and Windows Boot Manager correctly selects to boot from HDD.

Lately I am no longer able to boot up the computer with the USB dongle attached. I have to unplug it for the computer to boot up. I can then re-attach it once Windows has started.

I checked the boot order in the BIOS. Nothing out of the ordinary there:

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. USB CD/DVD
3. USB FDD
4. HDD
5. USB external HDD
   etc.

I hit F12 at boot to look at the boot order:

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. HDD
3. USB external drive
   etc

Nothing seems out of the ordinary, the boot order is correct, but with the dongle plugged in, the computer gets stuck on the screen that says Starting Windows and I don't get the spinning balls. It just remains stuck.

I attempted a repair but of course there is nothing to repair.

Not a huge problem but it is annoying nonetheless.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: Notice, you are *not* booting from HDD, you are booting from Windows Boot Manager. WBM might be getting confused. I suggest putting your HDD first to see if that helps.

Comment: Details of "won't boot" please

Comment: Vivid Kraig, shouldn't the WBM be first normally?

Comment: Moab, you know how the first thing you see is Starting Windows, then a little circle with spinning balls comes up? All I get is the Starting Windows message, and I don't even get the spinning balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like there isn't much to solve here. The problem disappeared on its own after the latest Windows update. Thanks to those who commented on the question.